# android image rotation custom duration

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-animation, android-imageview

I'm trying to rotate an image with animation.
I wrote the animation xml code and rotate is working perfect

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="600"
    android:startOffset="0"/>
</set>
```

I have a problem. As you can see, the animation's duration is 600, but I want to set a custom duration.
I mean I want to finish rotating when my Asynctask has finished in the `onPostExecute()` method.

```
 final ImageView load = (ImageView) rightView.findViewById(R.id.u_load_unicoins);
        imageRotationAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.imagerotation);
        load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                load.startAnimation(imageRotationAnimation);

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        refreshUnicoin(load);

                    }
                }, 1000);


            }
        });
```

I also tried to use clearAnimation, but my animation has a static duration in my xml file.
How I can solve my problem?

Comment: You want a image to rotate until your task finish?

Comment: @Nanoc yes you are right

Comment: use repeat and when task completes just cancel it

Comment: i added android:repeatCount="infinite" in my xml file and  i have not clearAnimation but rotating automaticly finished @AntonShkurenko Shkurenko

Comment: That attribute seems to be ignored from xml, try to set it programatically, once you have loaded the animation you can call imageRotationAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);

Comment: use android:repeatCount="infinite" in your xml file and onPostExecute method clear the animation using  load.clearAnimation().